# whats the solution for Cannot cast com.google.gson.JsonArray to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Tags: java

My Json Array looks like this

```
 [
   {
      "geoRegion":"101",
      "companyName":"101",
      "department":"101",
      "industry":"101",
      "sector":"101",
      "formName":"101",
      "formType":true,
      "fields":[
         {
            "labelId":"102",
            "bizJust":"101"
         },
         {
            "labelId":"103",
            "bizJust":"101"
         },
         {
            "labelId":"104",
            "bizJust":"101"
         },
         {
            "labelId":"129",
            "bizJust":"102"
         },
         {
            "labelId":"128",
            "bizJust":"102"
         },
         {
            "labelId":"144",
            "bizJust":"102"
         },
         {
            "labelId":"143",
            "bizJust":"102"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My code is as following:

```
    public Map<String,String> createTransaction(String lang) throws Exception {

            Gson gson =new Gson();
            JsonObject jsonObj=gson.fromJson(lang, JsonObject.class);//Exception thrown at this line
}
```

Comment: The solution is to convert to a `JsonArray` when it's an array, and to a `JsonObject` when it's an object.

Answer (score 3):

Try to get all the content into the JSON Array instead of the JSON Object.

Change your code from

```
JsonObject jsonObj=gson.fromJson(lang, JsonObject.class);
```

to:

```
JsonArray array = gson.fromJson(lang, JsonArray.class);
```

Comment: But then how to fetch the values from this JsonArray

Comment: There is a few approaches how to parse JSON Array. You have to know what you need. You can, for example, define your classes get everything you need using gson (better). Or you can parse directly through the structure over loops to get some data, or something third...